# objective-c sortedArrayUsingSelector alphabetical and numerical

Tags: objective-c

I have an array like so:

```
FileFolderData *ffd = [[datasource.finalData valueForKey:[[[datasource.finalData allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

and this sorts it alphabetically, but I need it sort numerically also, is this possible?

Comment: What does your data look like? Is it strings containing numbers, e.g. values like @"some string 001"?

Comment: Put the array that you are sorting that we can get what are you trying to sort !